# Deleting a class object from a Random Access File and "re-writing" the file in Java

Tags: java, object, randomaccessfile

thank you for being patient. I wanted to try a few things before re-posting. I changed the code to pull information from the file, edit the information using an arraylist and writing the updated information to a 'new' .dat file. (Sorry about the format, not sure why some of the code is pasted above the code editor...)

public class UserDeletedStudentFile 
{
    StudentInformation studentInfo;         // Declare a StudentInformation object
    CollectStudentInformation file;         // Declare a CollectStudentInformation object

```
// This constructor makes a copy of the StudentInformation object passed by the infoObject argument...
public UserDeletedStudentFile(StudentInformation infoObject)
{
    studentInfo = new StudentInformation(infoObject);
}

// This no-arg constructor allows access from the DemoStudentAdmin.java class...
public UserDeletedStudentFile() {};

// getStudentInformation() returns a copy of the StudentInformation object with student name and ID number...
public StudentInformation getStudentInformation()
{   return new StudentInformation(studentInfo);   } 

// deleteStudentFile() deletes a student file as needed by the user...
public void deleteStudentFile() throws IOException
{
    String userInput = "";          // For user input
    int userToFileTransition = 0;   // Subracting one from the user's choice to read the record needed
    int selectionNumber = 0;        // Number for user to choose
    int indexNumber = 0;

    // Open a new studentDirectory.dat and populate the ArrayList<>...
    file = new CollectStudentInformation("studentFileDirectory.dat");

    // Create an ArrayList<>...
    ArrayList<StudentInformation> studentFiles = new ArrayList<>();

    // Populate the ArrayList<> with the information from the StudentInformation class...
    for(int y = 0; y < file.getNumberOfRecords(); y++)
    {
        file.moveFilePointer(y);
        studentInfo = file.readStudentFile();
        studentFiles.add(studentInfo);
    } 

    // Ask the user if they wish to see one record, all records of currently enrolled students or Quit the menu option...
    while(selectionNumber < 1 || selectionNumber > 3)
    {
        userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "\n\nPlease choose from one of the following options:" +
                                                      "\nPress '1' for the student record number" +
                                                      "\nPress '2' for the Mars University directory" +
                                                      "\nPress '3' to return to the main menu.");
        selectionNumber = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
    }

    // Display the selection choices...
    if(selectionNumber == 1)
    {
        // Get a record number from the user, subtract 1 and display...
        userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the record number you wish to delete: "); 
        userToFileTransition = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
        indexNumber = (userToFileTransition - 1);              // pulling from the array, not the random access file...

        // Read the record at that location...
        studentInfo = studentFiles.get(indexNumber);

        // Display the student information for the user to verify...
        System.out.println("\n" + studentInfo.getfirstName());
        System.out.println(studentInfo.getLastName());
        System.out.println(studentInfo.getStudentID());

        // Remove the student file...
        studentFiles.remove(indexNumber);

        // Testing for the correct number of elements in the arrayList...
        for(StudentInformation student : studentFiles) 
            System.out.println(student);

        //Create an CollectStudentInformation object...
        file = new CollectStudentInformation("studentFileDirectory.dat");

        for(int x = 0; x < studentFiles.size(); x++)
            file.writeStudentFile(studentFiles.get(x));
    }

    // Clear the ArrayList<> of all values...
    studentFiles.clear();

    // close the file...
    file.close();

    // Return to the main() to access the menu...              
    DemoStudentAdmin.main(null);
```

So... each class (Create, Read, Modify and Delete) are created in the same way with only the 'Delete' class not writing the updated ArrayList (studentFiles). Instead, it will remove the requested object and replace that element with a copy of the following object. trimToSize() does not work in this instance, either.

Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Since there are only five students....Dump the file contents into an ArrayList and close file. Allow the User to do what is needed using the ArrayList as the data source. If a Add, Edit, or Delete had been requested and carried out then make the necessary changes to the specific record contained within the ArrayList then overwrite the the **data File** by dumping the ArrayList contents into file in the same format as when the file was originally created.

Comment: To build a new file and when done replace the old is a much easier prolem to solve than rewriting the file "in place", but if you really need to do it, I believe the java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel (since 1.7) is what you're looking for.